# Why this code has findDOMNode warning first time open the dialog?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

Always got this error when the first time open this dialog:

> Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was
>   passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead,
>   add a ref directly to the element you want to reference

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {Button, Modal, Form} from "react-bootstrap";

class ClusterBar extends Component {
    state = { show: false, clusterName: '', clusterConfigure: '' };

    handleClose = () => this.setState({show: false});
    handleShow = () => this.setState({show: true});
    handleSave = () => {        
        this.setState({show: false});
        console.log(this.state.clusterName, this.state.clusterConfigure);
    }

    handleClusterNameChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({clusterName: event.target.value});
    }
    handleClusterConfigureChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({clusterConfigure: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <>
            <div className="list-group">
                <Button className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">cluster One</Button>
                <Button className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">cluster Two</Button>
                <Button className="list-group-item list-group-item-action">cluster Three</Button>
                <Button className="list-group-item list-group-item-action" onClick={this.handleShow}>+</Button>
            </div>
            <Modal show={this.state.show} onHide={this.handleClose}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Add a cluster</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="formClusterName">
                    <Form.Label>Cluster Name</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="text" onChange={this.handleClusterNameChange} />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="formClusterConfigure">
                    <Form.Label>Connnection Configure</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows="3" onChange={this.handleClusterConfigureChange} />
                </Form.Group>
            </Form>                
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.handleClose}>
                Cancel
                </Button>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.handleSave}>
                Save
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
            </Modal>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ClusterBar
```

Comment: Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here:

Comment: The problem is known and this warning should show only in dev mode.

Relevant issue: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/5075